# Android Eclipse add "Button-like state" to listview items

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, states

What is the quickest way to set your list view items so that when you click on them they flash to a different state to let the user know they clicked on it?  Something like a quick image change, color change, border color, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you create a selector for the listview using colors..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/grey" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/blue" />

</selector>
```

Here is an excellent tutorial.[Customizing Listview selected color](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html)

Comment: Would that xml go inside of the <ListView> tags, or is that defined as its own xml file?

Comment: That would be its own XML file. Check out the tutorial. Shows you COMPLETELY how to do it. Really in-depth

Comment: It even shows you how to create a selector or customize the text or an image inside the ListView when its clicked.

Comment: Nice to know this Coder_For_Life22. Very simple yet I never think of it. I'm using this...Upvote for u